# Are cookies shared between tabs and, for example, bots in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm wondering if HTTP requests to bots can share cookies set by a website in a tab.

If an HTTP response in a tab contains "Set-Cookie" and the bot is on the same domain as the tab, will these cookies be embedded in the request header?

Or, more generally, is some environment shared between different components of a Teams application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to use cookie from tab in the bot.